# How to package the assets of a game and allow only the engine to be able to read?

Tags: c++, binary, filesystems, game-engine

I'm developing an engine for a 2D game in C ++ and for some days I've been looking for a way to protect the images and audio of my future game. I know there is no 100% protection and that someone would be able to open these files, but I mean the regular user who just installed the game, prevent it from modifying the sprites, change the sound, overwrite the xml files with game map data.

I downloaded some games made in Unity and noticed that a .assets extension is used, in Diablo 2 it is used .ma0, .mpq, .data, in FEZ .pak, in Super Meat Boy only a .tp file. In other words, you can not open and edit any of these files in a text editor or unzip with winrar, they offer a minimum level of protection. How is this done? Do I have to create my own binary file format or is there any program that makes it easier to work?

Comment: Why not just encrypt the files? Or save them as binary files, or serialise them?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

That "minimum level of protection" is even more minimal than you think. You can open those files in a hex editor and hack away at them. This activity is something that has been commonplace for many decades.

You can encrypt the data, but since the key must be stored in your application and the user has a copy of your application, that can be extracted and/or changed too.

You can add a digital signature to prevent people from modifying the assets then using them ("modding") but, again, this can be altered in your application.

You can obfuscate the assets by shipping them in a proprietary format, but this is usually done purely for functional reasons because, again, someone *will* reverse engineer them.

**Once a thing is on someone else's computer, you have lost control of that thing.**

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer, you're right, but I do not believe that people with this level of knowledge will not be interested in changing images of an indie little 2D game, maybe a game from a big company would be a better target for all of this effort. I just want to protect the archives of evil children.

Comment: @William If you are happy with the obfuscation level of protection then this'll do :)

Answer (score 1):

There are actually multiple questions here, iirc:

- How can users be prevented from reading game assets?
- How can users be prevented from manipulating game assets?
- What file format can be used to store game assets?

If you're using an existing engine, it probably has some support for this, and if it is sufficient for your purposes you only need to learn how to use it.

If you need to roll your own, you need to define your requirements clearly and pick a solution which fulfills them. For asset storage, a ZIP based format is probably easiest to handle, all languages have some form of support for that. To protect integrity, you should use cryptographic algorithms: digital signatures to detect tampering, and encryption to prevent reading. These will probably slow down the opening of assets a little bit, but in most cases this should be acceptable.

Comment: I was thinking of using a library like zlib to zip and unzip the files, but adding some change in the bits that would stay in the code during writing and reading, I do not know if that is possible, and finally changing the extension so it is not so obvious that s it's a zip

Comment: Changing the extension won't help. Anybody suspecting your game assets are there will look for that format first. Security by obscurity isn't really secure.